# Button click navigation with C#

Tags: c#, button, web, webbrowser-control, navigateurl

I want to make sure that when the button is clicked on the next page. I tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ffffffffffffgd
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
            //
        }
        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.scifi.hu");
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://onlinepont-online.cc");
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://filmbolond-onlinefilm.net");
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.mafab.hu");
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://lichess.org/");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: Please provide your aspx code as well. Maybe your button is missing runer="server" or something.

Comment: *I want to make sure that when the button is clicked on the next page* then what?

Comment: Same as the first page (https://www.scifi.hu). Do not go to the next page.